# angular ngClass evaluation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class

I've been learning AngularJs and have built a very basic Angular app. In one part of the app, I've used [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) at a div element like

```
<div ng-class='{"some class": aFuncTruthyOrFalsy()}'>
<!-- aFuncTruthyOrFalsy() is defined in the controller for this view-->
```

Now, there's an input element in the view that is non-related to the above element and does not relate at all to any of the values checked in the function above.

I noticed that every whenever I type something in the input field (change event, keypressed event) it causes a re-evaluation of the ngClass. (I've put in a console log inside the aFuncTruthyOrFalsy function). I'm not able to determine which all events are bubbling to cause the reevaluation.

It seems to me that ngClass reevaluates at every single event in the page.

**Can anyone please explain/elaborate this behavior?**

**Is it possible to cache the evaluated class at the initial load of the view?**

What if there are multiple ngClass being used in the same view and each of the expression evaluation is delegated to some function that again does some multiple operation to come to get the evaluated expression?

Comment: It is bound to the angular digest cycle, which is intended. This is because the intention of `ng-class` is to change the class on changes of the bound variable. If you only want to bind once, you can do something like `class="{{ ::(aFuncTruthyOrFalsy() ? 'some class' : '') }}`

Comment: @devqon, Thanks. Can you please direct me to a good resource that explains this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular binding is using $watch to monitor changes in the function value. The digest cycle is calling your function to compare the result with last value.

This article is nice explaining this
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/watch-digest-apply.html#watch

I suggest binding to scope variables instead of functions. i.e. have a variable in the scope that will store result of that function, and you update that whenever required.

after all you don't want to call methods from your view probably.Your current setup leaves the door open to make the whole MVC concept void,e.g. someone later add functionality inside that method that was supposed to be just a getter.

Comment: Will the digest function call the function that I'm calling for evaluation inside ngClass if it is defined in one controller and the model (input field) that I'm updating is in another controller scope?

Comment: It does! Angular is not smart enough to know that other controller functions do not need to be executed. the $apply() bubbles up and then calls $digest() in all controllers which will evaluate the $watch() first parameter.

Comment: see this plunker. two controllers isolated, but still you see logs for both    http://plnkr.co/edit/tW0wgtt1cWzRa7hw2mcH?p=info

Comment: So, it doesn't matter if it is in the child scope or not.

Answer (score 1):

When something is changed in the scope AngularJS automatically triggers a $digest cycle by calling $digest(). When the $digest cycle starts, it fires each of the watchers.

Angular sets up a watcher on the scope model, which in turn updates the view whenever the model changes.

So when you change something in the scope, all the watchers are fired and the model is reevaluated.

Here is a good article on the topic: [Link](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/)

Comment: If function called for evaluation is in a different controller and the model being updated in a different controller.

Comment: Processes all of the watchers of the current scope and its children. Your controllers must not be nested.

Comment: Yes, they are nested. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
 <div ng-class="{'background1': color.back}">
    <label> <span>{{emp.comp}}</span> </label>
  </div>
```

Comment: I know I can do this. Sorry, this is not my question.